# how to replace some content in mail template before send in C#?

Tags: c#, html, email, send

I have create a mail template ,but some value will be dynamic from cs file , I try to using ##username in my mail template ,
and using mailbody.Replace("##UserName", "jack"); to replace the username  value in mail template ，but it's still show ##UserName in my mail,
please how to replace some content in mail template before send in C# ?

my mail template : mailtemplate.html :

```
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> ##UserName<span style='font-size:24px'><span></td>
            </tr>
           
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

my sendmail.aspx.cs :

```
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
 string mailbody = string.Empty;
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("mailtemplate.html")))
 {
      mailbody = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
mailbody.Replace("##UserName", "jack");
mm.Body = mailbody;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just using your "original" mailbody.

You need to do sth like this

`mailbody = mailbody.Replace("##UserName", "jack");`

Then `mailbody` will have the replaced text....if not you are just replacing, but throwing away the result...

In C# strings are inmutable, so you get a NEW one, with desired replacement

So this

```cs
mailbody = mailbody.Replace("##UserName", "jack");
mm.Body = mailbody;
```

or this

```cs
var replacedBody = mailbody.Replace("##UserName", "jack");
mm.Body = replacedBody;
```

or this

```cs
mm.Body = mailbody.Replace("##UserName", "jack");;
```

should work. You just need to work with the returned value of `Replace` not with the original string (what you are doing)

Take a look [here at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0). Replace returns a `string`, which is the result string you are looking for

Comment: In other words, string.Replace() actually doesn't modify the string but returns a new string.

Comment: Right. It returns a new string with the modified text. The original keeps untouched.  This is so in C#, strings are inmutable. That's why there is for ex. a `StringBuilder` for when you need to dinamically create strings.  Please accept my answer if helped :)